# How to make linux shell interpret a .pyc file with python in /usr/bin?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, python, compiling

I have the file, `myapp`, that is a `.pyc` file, and I want to make it executable. Currently, I must manually call Python to execute the program, as follows.

```
python /usr/bin/myapp "hello world!"
```

How can I permanently configure the system to execute `myapp` without manually invoking `python`, as follows?

```
myapp "hello world!"
```

I need to do this because the shebang, `#!/usr/bin/env python`, does not work in  byte-compiled `.pyc` files without using a separate `.sh` wrapper script.

Comment: @Christopher Works Fine!, binfmt-support work perfect, can you post as a answer? to select your answer as best...

Comment: @Christopher I wait you, no worries...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Debian-based distributions, the package, `binfmt-support`, provides the functionality. Look in the procedure file system for the formats that were configured with installation of the package.

```
ls /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
```

Make sure to also give the `.pyc` file/s permission to execute.

Comment: Thank you Christopher!, works fine...